# Getline leitura, não le a string e tb quando acessa um vetor que nao existe ou tamanho insufiente

Tags: c++, runtime

bem, essa é uma classificacao de jogadores de uma partida de dois em dois, onde classifica a partida em que parou.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,Ri,Ei,partidas,tamanho,contador,posicao1,i,achar,total1,total2;
    string palavra;

    cin>>N;

    partidas=N/2;
    achar=0;
    int demora[N+5],classificacao[N+5],rapidez[N+5],total[N+5];

    contador=0;
    while(contador<N)
    {//Lê a quantidade de jogadores
        cin>>Ri>>Ei;

        demora[contador]=Ri;
        rapidez[contador]=Ei;
        classificacao[contador]=0;

        contador++;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,palavra);
    //cout<<palavra<<" esse é o tamnho"<<endl;

    tamanho=palavra.length();
    contador=1;//partida de numero 1

    total[0]=(rapidez[0]*tamanho)+demora[0];
    for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    {//vai me cada vetor e classifica os jogadores
        total[i]=(rapidez[i]*tamanho)+demora[i];

        if(total[i]>total[i-1])
        {//classifica primeira variavel perdedor
            classificacao[i]=contador;
            classificacao[i-1]=contador+1;//vai pra proxima rodada
            i++;
        }
        else
        {//classifica a segunda variavel perdedor
            classificacao[i-1]=contador;
            classificacao[i]=contador+1;//vai pra proxima rodada
            i++;
        }
    }

    contador=2;//Partidas dois se houver entra no while
    while(partidas!=1)
    {//

        //para as partidas
        i=0;
        while(i<N)
        {//percorre s o vetor


            while(achar!=1)
            {//achar o primeiro
                if(classificacao[i]==contador)
                {//o primeiro participante
                    posicao1=i;
                    total1=(tamanho*contador*rapidez[i])+demora[i];
                    achar=1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            //continuar procurando aprtir do primeiro
            while(achar!=2)
            {//achar o primeiro
                if(classificacao[i]==contador)
                {//o primeiro participante

                    total2=(tamanho*contador*rapidez[i])+demora[i];
                    achar=2;

                    if(total1>total2)
                    {//
                        classificacao[i]=contador+1;//vai pra proxima rodada
                    }
                    else
                    {//classifica a segunda variavel perdedor
                        classificacao[posicao1]=contador+1;//vai pra proxima rodada
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        achar=0;
        contador++;//qual partida esta
        partidas/=2;//dimuniu as partidas
        tamanho*=2;//cada rodada o tamanho da string muda
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {

            if(i==N-1)
            {
                cout<<classificacao[i]<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<classificacao[i]<<" ";
            }
    }
}
```

exemplo de entrada que deve ser:

4

4 1

3 1

2 1

1 1

ABCD

as vezes imprime normal, mas nao considera o tamanho da string outras vezes da runtime error.

Comment: Não deu para perceber o problema, tente ser o mais detalhado possivel. "as vezes imprime normal" - e nas vezes que não imprime normal imprime o que ? E qual a linha de código que dá a impressão errada ? qual o `while` que "vai ao infinito" ? Atenção ao intercalar de `getline` e `cin >> ` que mediante as quebras de linha e os tipos usados pode não funcionar como espera.

Comment: É a entrada da quebra de linha que não le o getline

Comment: Fiz um pequeno teste e não vi nenhum problema em relação ao `cin` e `getline`. Veja o [teste no ideone](https://ideone.com/emVk2s). O `cin.ignore();` que tem antes do `getline` já consome a quebra de linha que fica para trás logo essa parte não tem problema.

Comment: mas vc nao colocou as quebras de linhas ficou assim https://ideone.com/vmgQAz e deu erro

Comment: O seu ultimo exemplo do ideone não tem valores de entrada. Você colocou os valores de entrada nas notas. No entanto, você pode dar Enter em branco numa leitura com `cin >>` num inteiro que só quando o inteiro for escrito é que a leitura irá ser efetuada, mas num `getline` um enter em branco é valido e lé uma string vazia. Por esse motivo entre `1 1` e `ABCD` não pode ter um Enter a mais.